# Как при закрытии дочерней формы установить значение переменной другого окна?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Есть класс MainWindow, в нем есть переменная Zindex. Как при закрытии дочерней формы установить значение переменной другого окна в методе close класса MChild?

```
public partial class MChild : UserControl
{    
    public void Close()
    {
      this.MwiParent.Children.Remove(this);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать [Application.Current.MainWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562358/accessing-mainwindows-controls-from-a-user-control-page-wpf-c-sharp) или [Window.GetWindow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302839/wpf-user-control-parent).

Answer (score 2):

в методе где вы вызываете MChild:

```
...
var ChildWindow = new MChild();
ChildWindiw.Owner = this;
ChildWindow.ShowDialod();
...
```

в методе Close() в ChildWindow:

```
...
MainWindow main = this.Owner as MainWindow;
main.Zindex = 42;
...
```

конечно, если я правильно понял ваш вопрос

Comment: MChild UserControl и Owner у него нет. Как быть?

Comment: чёрт, не заметил метку [wpf](http://hashcode.ru/questions/tagged/wpf/)

Answer (score 2):

Усложни логику работы дочернего окна: создавай его скрытым, а для показа напиши что-то вроде:

```
private UserControl parent = null; //<- переменная для хранения вызвавшего контрола
public void ShowEx(UserControl parent)
{
     this.parent = parent;
     this.Show();
}
```

Показываешь дочернее окно, вызывая код из главного:

```
var ChildWindow = new MChild();
ChildWindow.ShowEx(this);
```

Ну и соответственно при закрытии дочерней формы:

```
public void Close()
{
    this.parent.ТвояПеременная = ТвоеЗанчение;
}
```

Изи же.